# Событие 'click' не срабатывает на вложенном в элемент тексте

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на круг срабатывало событие "click". Но оно отрабатывает только за границами надписи "Нажмите на кнопку". Я делаю это через делегирование. Навешиваю класс на весь документ и потом через event.target.className проверяю условие: если это "circle" , тогда выведи alert. Но я не понимаю,почему не срабатывает на тексте. Спасибо за ответ.`введите сюда код`

```js
function clickFunction(event) {
            if (event.target.className == 'circle') {
                alert('нажал')
            }
        }
document.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);
```

```css
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <span class="circle__text">Нажмите на круг</span>
</div>
```

Comment: замените ``` event.target.className == 'circle' ``` на ``` event.target.closest('.circle') ```

Comment: @Макск, спасибо, помогло

Comment: Объясните зачем на document вешать событие?

Comment: @Greg--, это называется делегированием обработки событий - оно удобно в тех ситуациях, когда нужно добавить общий слушатель события возникающего на множестве элементов (включая элементы, добавляемые в DOM динамически), и/или когда нужно соблюдать очередность выполнения обработчиков, и т.д.. Работает делегирование благодаря механике распространения событий в DOM (сначала захват - движение "сверху вниз" по дереву, затем всплытие - "снизу вверх". В коде из вопроса, используется всплытие).

Comment: Про всплытие и погружение я знаю, я не встречал еще в проектах чтоб на document вешали, по этому и спрашиваю. В чем удобаство я не совсем понимаю, нужно же условия писать что если клик на таком то элементе то... или написать напрямую слушателя на этот же элемент, получается и там и там условие писать.

Comment: Т.е. представьте у вас есть формы, модальные окна, кнопки, баннеры, реклама и при каждом клике запускаются проверки?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clickFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.target.className);
    
    if (event.target.className == 'circle') {
        alert('нажал')
    }
    
    if (event.target.className == 'circle__text') {
        alert('нажал circle__text')
    }
}
document.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span class="circle__text">Нажмите на круг</span>
</div>
```

а лучше `event.target.className.includes('circle__text')` потому что классов может быть несколько

Comment: А если в "circle" будет множество вложенных элементов. Мне для всех условия прописывать?

Comment: Ну тебе же не нужно делать **конкретное действие** при клике на все вложенные элементы? А если нужно, тогда в отлове конкретного кликнутого элемента в принице никакого смысла нет

Comment: @IvanCoin В таких случаях делегирование и не нужно) ```document.querySelector(".circle__text").addEventListener("click",nameFunc)```

Comment: @Locker если кликнуть на div то не сработает )

Comment: @Макск Это пример, можно поставить родителя и все будет работать, как текст так и родитель

Answer (score 0):

> А если в "circle" будет множество вложенных элементов. Мне для всех
> условия прописывать?

В данном случае вам понадобится 'closest', который возвращает ближайший родительский элемент. А для понимания природы клика рекомендую — [Всплытие и погружение](https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing).

```js
function clickFunction(event) {
  if (event.target.closest('.circle')) { 
    console.log('.circle');
  } else {
    alert('Упс — мимо.)')
  }
}
document.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
.square {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.circle_small {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="circle_small">
      <span class="text">Нажмите куда попало в области большого круга</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```